# Convert Expo managed workflow to bare React Native

Tags: expo, workflow, managed, bare

I am going to convert current expo project from Expo managed workflow to bare React Native to use react-native-branch.

I run this command on terminal.

```
expo eject
```

I can run app on local environment, but debug and release apk is not working.

Answer (score 4):

Expo eject is deprecated. You can use "npx expo prebuild" to create android and ios folders, you'll want to read up more on it here: https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/prebuild/